# Discord py nickname, on_member_update

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```py
@bot.event
async def on_member_update(before, after):   
if before == bannedwords:
        await after.edit(nick=before.nick)
        if before == bannedwords:
            await after.edit(nick=before.nick)
        else:
            await after.edit(nick=before.nick)
    print("old nick: ", before.nick)
    print("new nick: ", after.nick)
```

My Code look like this.

My goal is to change the name whenever the nickname is changed, AND when it includes bad words.

for ex)
/nick (cursing words)
bot changes name into temporary name

**IT WORKS FINE** if we change our name like
[image]

**BUT NOT LIKE** [image]

Comment: In your function you check whether `before`(a discord.Member) == `bannedwords`, which is probably a list and will never return true. What you might want to check instead is `if after.nick in bannedwords`. Also why do you edit the nickname twice?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The first nick edit things is for checking.